# Regex replaces everything that matches any character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, variables

```
a[b].innerHTML=a[b].innerHTML.replace(RegExp('['+bbc[c][0]+']','ig'),bbc[c][1])
```

This is basically what I'm working with. It's wrapped in two loops so that should explain why it looks like what it does. Basically I want to replace something that matches '['+variable from an array+']'. I'm making a BBCode script for a free forum and no don't point me at any BBCode scripts.
The problem is that regex is replacing everything that matches any character. So, it replaces [, q, c, o, d, e, ], all with the second part of the array. (QCODE is an example BBCode being used) I don't know if it does that in a normal /regex/ with [] but it's annoying as hell. I've tried escaping the [] ('\['+v+'\]'), I've tried eval(), I've tried everything you can imagine. I need to make this thing work like it's supposed to, because everything is set up as it should be. If you know how to fix this, please answer. I'd like you to test your solution before answering though because you have **no** idea how many methods I've tried to make this work.

Comment: To test your exact case, we need to know a[b].innerHTML and bbc[c][0].

Comment: As TNi suggests, you need to provide one or more unit tests.

Comment: Anything with brackets around a variable. It doesn't matter. As I said in the post, qcode is an example. It just needs to replace brackets around a specified variable with ANYTHING as long as it doesn't replace EVERYTHING that matches any letter of the variable. So only replace [qcode] in "This bbcode is " rather than "This bb is" (replacing code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is because you are using RegExp, which takes in a string for a regular expression. In this string, you need to escape the backslash escape character. The following will work:

```
​var str = 'Before. [qcode] After.';
alert(str.replace(RegExp('\\[qcode\\]', 'ig'), 'During.'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: That does work. It seems like something I should've thought of. If only I could rate your answer high more than once, thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

Use the right escape character:

```
RegExp('\\['+bbc[c][0]+'\\]','ig'),
```

`/` is just a regular character (except in regex literals, which you're not using), the escape character is `\`.  You also have to escape twice, once for the string literal, and once for the regex.

Comment: The post was a typo because I was rushing. I used the right escape character, it didn't work. That's why I said test before answering.

Comment: If you haven't seen I have, a minute before your response.

Comment: @Ruffian, you actually need to use `'\\\['` , because you're escaping once for the string literal, and once for the regex.  I left that out before.

Comment: I didn't see your updated answer before I posted mine. Good job. The lesson learned from all this is that problem typos distract from the real issue. I've seen this error made very often, but because I was confused from the question, didn't catch it right away.